# Silverlight Webpart Custom Initialization Parameters in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: silverlight-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I have a xap file which accepts custom parameters.I have tested it in a HTML page.It works.

```
"<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="SmoothStreamingPlayer.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <param name="InitParams" value="selectedcaptionstream=textstream_eng,mediaurl=http://ie1adtvmvrb1s:12345/LiveSmoothVideo.isml/manifest" />
            </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>"
```

---

Here I am passing Intialization parameters like this

selectedcaptionstream=textstream_eng,mediaurl=http://ie1adtvmvrb1s:12345/LiveSmoothVideo.isml/manifest

I am trying to place the same intialization parameters in Silverlight Webpart in Sharepoint 2010. But It didn't load the Xap filele to.I am not able to figure out what is going wrong

Answer (score 1):

When you add the SP Silverlight WP, one of the parameters in the tool part is under "Other Settings > Custom Initialization Parameters" you can define them there.